# JTattoo appears in JMenu dropdown

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jmenu

I used JTattoo in my java file successfully. But The "JTattoo" word appears in the drop down on JMenu. Is there any way to get rid of it? or Can i replace that Text?

Comment: I never see that, for better help sooner edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrated your issue

Answer (score 6):

On their website their is a suggestion you require a license key for this. See [this page](http://www.jtattoo.net/HowTo_ChangeLogo.html), which I found behind a 'How to change the logo text in popup menus.' link .

Comment: I don't want to have any company name in the popup menu. When I put `null` for logoString I face exception. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `setTheme()` with three arguments, setting the first to the theme which you prefer and setting the other ones to an empty String (NOT `null`, just the String `""`); here's an example for the LaF "Texture" and the theme "Textile":

```
TextureLookAndFeel.setTheme("Textile", "", "");
```

I checked the license but didn't notice anything against doing so. If it is forbidden by the license or something similar, please someone tell me that.

Answer (score 1):

According to JTattoo site:
http://www.jtattoo.net/HowTo_ChangeLogo.html
you can use this code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("logoString", "my company");
AeroLookAndFeel.setCurrentTheme(props);
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.aero.AeroLookAndFeel");
```

You can change your lookandfeel, i.e. AluminiumLookAndFeel.set...